# Can I get popups on mouseover for inline documentation in Sublime Text?

Tags: lua, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm used to Android Studio, which has these awesome popups when you hover your cursor over a function (or anything else), which shows you a description, parameters, etc.. Now I'm using Sublime Text 3 for Lua programming, and I would like to have a similar thing. I would prefer something that allows for inline documentation.

I found something called [ToolTip-Helper](https://github.com/doobleweb/ToolTip-Helper) and tried it out, but I couldn't get it to work unfortunately. I created the inline documentation as they describe, and placed my mouse over a function call further down, but no popup showed unfortunately. It does however resemble exactly what I'm looking for. Inline documentation and a simple popup on mouseover on a formula.

Does anyone know a tool that does these things, or perhaps know how to get ToolTip-Helper working?